# How to check if 2 connections are from the same host

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

currently im using this code to manage a listener than can listen from multiple clients

```
 
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 5005))
server_socket.listen()
server_socket.setblocking(False)


connections = []
 
try:
    while True:
        try:
            connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()

            connection.setblocking(False)
            connections.append(connection)
        except BlockingIOError:
            pass
 
        for i, connection in enumerate(connections):
            try:

                data = connection.recv(2)
                while data[-1] != 10:
                    newdata = connection.recv(2)
                    data += newdata
                
                print(f'I got data: {data}!')

            except BlockingIOError:
                pass
 
finally:
    server_socket.close()
```

How can I check wether 2 connections are from the same host using `connection` or `client_address`

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem here is since the answer seems to be obvious to me. To check if something is the same as another thing compare it to the other. To check if the client hosts are the same compare them. The get the client host use `client_address[0]`. You can also get client_address later from the socket connection by calling getpeername on it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is correct. Also, you need to consider how to safely terminate receipt of incoming data. If the client disconnects you'll get an empty bytes object and a consequential IndexError